# Ducts Spray Foam vs. Wrapping

Tags: hvac, insulation, ducts

I'm having some condensation issues with ducts in my basement.  Based on what I've read, it sounds like I have to get a dehumidifier and wrap the ducts.

I've wrapped a few, but it's hard to get the seal really tight the way I'd like it.

I was going to have them wrapped professionally.  But someone suggested that I could have them covered in closed cell foam to make a tighter seal.  Which do you think is better?

Comment: "Better" is a subjective term. You're asking us to weigh cost and benefit, and therefore this question is off-topic. Perhaps you could revise to ask something more specific about the products.

Comment: Condensation occurs when warm, humid air meets cold. Does this condensation only happen when you're running air conditioning (and not heat)? Is your basement conditioned (eg: ducts heating/cooling it)? Does it have a similar humidity to the rest of the house, or is it sealed off? Is there some extra source of humidity in the basement? Insulating the ducts to me sounds like fixing the symptom, not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Covered in foam would be a better seal and offer insulation (minor) and sound deadening for air traveling through the duct.  It would also probably cost your first born child depending on the company, their quality, the size and access of ducts, etc.  There is duct mastic that may work better for some areas, smears around like bondo.  Maybe explain your condensation issue more in depth?  That sounds odd depending on your climate and the setup.